# How to send notification to activity tab of Microsoft teams using Teamsjs?

Tags: java, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I am working on a MS teams notification bot. I am able to send notification, I am getting a card banner as soon as notification is received. I have used adaptive cards for content. I want to show that notification in Activity feed too, so that the user still has a reminder to which he should respond.
I am not able to find any reference information on how to achieve that.

I am using

```
context.sendActivity(notification);
```

to send notification.

How can I show the same notification in Activity feed ?

[image]

I have researched, but most of the articles point to microsoft Graph API. Which I am not using. I am looking for some way to implement this without using graph api

Comment: You need to implement this using Graph API only.
You can use the activity feed notification APIs in Microsoft Graph to extend this functionality to your apps.
Ref sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/csharp